# How to use a Class Decorator in Typescript to modify all of the Classes' Static Methods?

Tags: typescript, express, class, decorator, static-methods

Let's say I have a class with many static methods. My goal is to wrap each static method with a function. Specifically, I want to catch `async` errors by applying `.catch` to each static method like so:

```
// In user-response.ts

const catchAsyncError = (func: Function) => {
  const catcher = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    func(req, res, next).catch(next);
  }
  return catcher;
}

class UserResponse {
  static createUser = catchAsyncError(createUser);
  static updateUser = catchAsyncError(updateUser);
  static deleteUser = catchAsyncError(deleteUser);
  // more static methods...
}


// In routes.ts

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/create-user', UserResponse.createUser);
router.patch('/update-user', UserResponse.updateUser);
router.delete('/delete-user', UserResponse.deleteUser);
```

The overarching goal of doing this is to avoid code repetition. Notice how I have to write `catchAsyncError(...)` repeatedly for each static method.

Also, the purpose of placing these functions in a class is to add some semantic context to each function. This way, a developer who is not familiar with the implementation of the various `user` related functions will know that they are related because they will read `UserResponse.createUser` instead of `createUser`.

I'm looking for a solution like this:

```
// In user-response.ts

const catchAsyncError = (func: Function) => {
  const catcher = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    func(req, res, next).catch(next);
  }
  return catcher;
}

@withCatchAsyncError
class UserResponse {
  static createUser = createUser;
  static updateUser = updateUser;
  static deleteUser = deleteUser;
  // more static methods...
}
```

How would I go about implementing a solution like this? Hopefully it's possible, for it is far more elegant and aesthetic than the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `withCatchAsyncError` class decorator will be getting the class constructor at runtime without detailed type information on it. Static class members are actually properties of the constructor, so the decorator will need to go through the constructor's properties, look for those that are themselves functions, and wrap them with `catchAsyncError`. Something like this:

```
function withCatchAsyncError(constructor: Function) {
  for (const key of Object.keys(constructor)) {
    if (typeof constructor[key] === 'function') {
      constructor[key] = catchAsyncError(constructor[key]);
    }
  }
}
```